# Module compiled with Swift 4.0.3 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2.1 compiler

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, swift4.2

I have my own library which was developed using swift 3.0.

Now I have migrated code to swift 4.2 and building using XCode 10.1. Still while using it in main project I am getting error as

**Module compiled with Swift 4.0.3 cannot be imported by the Swift 4.2.1 compiler**

Please provide solution to this.

I have set command line tools as below image:
[image]

Comment: i have also same issue in my project because i have mac 2010 late and new update is incompatible in this mac my project in this mac runs good but when i build my project in another mac (latest) this same issue happens

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on ProjectName.xcodeproj (or .xcworkspace for cocoa pods) file and open with Xcode 10.0(maybe works with 10.1) and build it.